# If a holomorphic map from an open disc to $\mathbb{C}^n$ extends continuously to the closed disc, what about its partial derivatives?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F$ be a holomorphic map from an open disc $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ and suppose $F$ extends continuously to $\overline{D}$.
Do the maps $\partial F_i / \partial z_k$ extend continuously to $\overline{D}$?

Thanks

Comment: Start with $n=1$: How does $\sqrt{1-z}$ behave?

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: Uitstekend, @Wim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial derivatives do not necessarily extend continuously to the closed disc. WimC gave $F(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$ as a counterexample in one dimension. In any dimension, $F(z)=(\sqrt{1-z_1},\dots,\sqrt{1-z_n})$ has the same property: each partial fails to have a continuous extension, and is not even bounded.

A situation in which one might *hope* for boundary smoothness is when $F$ is a biholomorphic map onto a  smooth domain. In one dimension there is a very satisfactory result called the [Kellogg-Warschawski theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Kellogg_theorem).  The situation in several variables is much more involved: see this [brief overview](http://www.aimath.org/research/projects/mappings/holo_maps.html).